# Add a custom http header to subdirectories

Tags: iis-6, http-headers

Here is the code I am using

```
cscript adsutil.vbs set w3svc/1/ROOT/Test/css/HttpCustomHeaders "Cache-Control: max-age=36000"
```

When I use it an error appears 
The path requested could not be found. 
ErrNumber: -2147024893 (0x80070003) Error 
Trying To Get the Object: w3svc/1/ROOT/Test/css
**w3svc/1/ROOT/Test** is the virtual directory

I want to apply my script to subdirectory **CSS** 
The question I have is it possible to apply to a subdirectory.